# Consumer is not getting down when processing time of the consumer exceeds more than max.poll.interval.ms

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to do a simple poc on spring kafka with spring boot with version (2.3.7 Release) to achieve how consumer batch process works, and how rebalance works if consumer takes more processing time as i am completely new to this messaging system.

Now i am seeing an issue with with kafka re balancing with single consumer (not allowed concurrency).

These are the properties i have set
max.poll.interval.ms = 50000 and factory.getContanerProperties.setIdealTimeBetweenPolls(120000)
and made the consumer batch process take more
than this max.poll.interval.ms. (70sec)
The issue i see here is  the consumer is getting triggered every 2 min interval and because of this, re balancing happening every 2 mins.  As per my understanding Actually this should not happen. Only first time the rebalance should happen.

Is there anything i am missing here?

Comment: Hey Mr_k I will help with this .
can you tell me how many publisher and subscriber are you using

Comment: we have one publisher to the topic and topic has 8 partitions. And one consumer is subscribed to that topic. And also i am trying to do the manual commit using acknowledgement.

Comment: then what the problem are you facing or what you trying to achive

Comment: And can you also share your KafkaConsumerConfiguration if u have

Comment: what my understanding is when consumer does not process records in max.poll.interval.time, the rebalancing should happen and next subsequent poll should not happen. But still the polling happening every 2 min and rebalance also happening.

Comment: For rebalance You need more then one concurrent consume  and because you are using one so there no concept of rebalance

Comment: i got what you say. But  i see still rebalance is happening with single consumer. is this the right behaviour ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228093/discussion-between-harkesh-kumar-and-mr-k).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a rebalance will always occur if you exceed `max.poll.interval.ms` - the broker thinks your consumer is dead so takes back the partitions (even if there are no more consumers).

When you next poll, the rebalance occurs and, since you only have one consumer, he gets all 8 partitions again.

Comment: Appreciate your input .Thanks harkesh kumar and @Gary Russell .  I tested with concurrent approach (8 consumers) with 1 consumer with more time exceeds poll interval and others with less time. I observed that consumer1  partition is leased and shared to the another consumer and saw the proper re balance happening.